# What do you call unclean water that you can't see through?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call unclean water that you can't see through? Probably contaminated with dirt, prolonged stagnation or mineral erosion, almost pale brown, like stagnated water on a rainy day.

Comment: Why does it have to be brown?  Post-Katrina, several Vermont lakes were dull green.   And from a technical point of view, water is highly absorptive, so you can't see more than a couple hundred feet in water that's devoid of suspended particles.  Presumably you're more interested in water with particulate levels high enough to block vision.

Comment: "Pale brown" was added just to give an mental simulation for what I wanted to convey... :)
I'm glad you cared to answer.

Comment: If the water is contaminated with dirt or sediment then "dirty water" seems the natural choice. Google ngrams shows that "dirty water" is generally more than twice as frequent as murky or turbid water (from 1780 till now). The Muddy Charles river separating Cambridge and Boston even has a [dedicated song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Water) by that name. "Love that murky water" just doesn't sound the same...

Comment: @Gone Quite possible "murky water" is trademarked by the same corporation which does marketing stats for Click&Clack, the Tappett Brothers :-)

Comment: As a non-native speaker, my guess would have been 'troubled': in Dutch the word is "troebel", which looks like it derives from the same stem; and that's how I always interpreted the song title "Bridge Over Troubled Water".  Or does "troubled water" have a different meaning, like "disturbed \[and therefore murky\] water"?

Comment: manky.................?

Comment: "Troubled" water isn't murky.  It's water that's stirred up.  There's an old spiritual: "Wade in the water...God's gonna trouble the water".  See John 5:4

Comment: Ontleend aan Oudfrans trouble ‘onzuiver’, ook torble, met metathese ontwikkeld uit vulgair Latijn *turbulus ‘onzuiver’, variant van klassiek Latijn turbidus ‘troebel, onzuiver, verwar(ren)d’, afgeleid van turba ‘verwarring, wanorde, opschudding’, zie → ***turbulent***.

Comment: You call it Blk! This water has minerals added to make it black. ![Blk](http://blogs.miaminewtimes.com/shortorder/blk%20water%202.jpg)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

***Murky*** comes to mind.

> *(of liquid) dark and dirty; not clear.*
> <sub>[Oxford learners dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/turbid)</sub>

Also consider ***Stagnant***:

> *having no current or flow and often having an unpleasant smell as a consequence*.
> <sub>[thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stagnant)</sub>

I expected ***Turbid*** to mean that the water has been stirred to produce the suspension of particles, but if the particles are small enough I would think it works.

> *Water is said to be turbid when particles suspended in it restrict the transmission of light and give a cloudy or muddy appearance. Only small particles can remain suspended for significant periods of time. Relatively large and dense particles such as sand grains will sink rapidly.*
> <sub>[EEA via dpi.vic.gov.au](https://www.eea.europa.eu/archived/archived-content-water-topic/wise-help-centre/glossary-definitions/turbid-waters)</sub>

Comment: I would hesitate to use "stagnant" because,strictly speaking, it only means "not moving," even tho' in colloquial use it implies smelly dirty water.

Comment: I think "stagnant" is appropriate as long as the water is also not moving.

Comment: *"...that you can't see though..."* sidelines stagnant, which describes only the state of flow. Turbid is most precise, followed closely by murky.

Comment: You are right about the "see through" bit but I wouldn't say stagnant *only* describes the state of flow. When I fill the bath up and turn the taps off, the water's not going anywhere but I'm not bathing in stagnant water either! Stagnant usually means it's been sitting around for a while and consequently has a bad smell (or some other negative consequence) as a result of that.

Comment: "Turbid" is a word that gets more use in technical circumstances, like geo- and environmental science. It means having stuff stirred up in it. See also "turbidity", and important water-quality metric. (Yes, it's not fitting for the OP's use.)

Comment: I have heard turbid used to describe the quality pond water that is infested with carp, since they are bottom feeders and stir up the sediment.

Comment: The graph shows that *turbid* needs our support.

Comment: For a noun, though, it doesn't have to be "murky water", just "murk" does fine.

Comment: +1 for murky. I thought about it as well.

Comment: Murky and turbid are the first two words that came to mind. 'Cloudy' is also applicable.

Comment: Because turbidity requires action of the water, whether stirring up or some other agitation, murky seems stronger and thus gets my +.

Comment: I don't think the graph proves much. I'm sure "clean water" would have far greater use -- doesn't mean it's the right word.

Comment: congrats on your gold badge :)

Answer (score 71):

You can use the adjective *[turbid](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turbid?q=turbid)*.

> **turbid**
>
> (of a liquid) cloudy, opaque, or thick with suspended matter. *the turbid estuary*

Or [feculent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feculent) which means *of or containing dirt, sediment, or waste matter*.

Comment: How odd, I've always associated "turbid" with a decrease in visibility caused by disturbance of the liquid itself (i.e. rough water) rather than any particulate matter or solute within it. I guess that happens sometimes when you only base your understanding of a word off of the various contexts you encounter it in rather than looking it up in the dictionary.

Comment: "turbid" is used a lot in the water treatment industry - specifically, they measure and record "turbidity"

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with it only in the context @JAB mentioned too.

Comment: "Turbid" doesn't mean unclean. It can be (and often is) used to indicate water that is clouded by inert or neutralised matter that is safe for drinking.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Like chalk?

Comment: @starsplusplus It's often in the context of a open-reservoir municipal water-treatment system after a storm when the filters are overwhelmed. Extra chemical treatment can render the remaining fine particles of runoff and lake bottom sterile, but unappetising-looking. The measure of visible particulate is called "turbidity", but is a measure that's independent of potability.

Comment: @JAB, probably also because you more or less unconsciously connect it with _turbulence_ (with which it does share etymological roots).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Now that you mention it, I think that is a big part of it too.

Comment: Turbid seems like the best word to describe unclean water that you cannot see through. Murky give the impression of mud. Turbid could be any unclean consistency.

Comment: I agree with turbid. Most of the other options either imply or dictate the type of impurity (feculent, dirty, muddy); and stagnant describes the state of motion, which only implies the turbidity. Also, turbidity can be quantified in various turbidity units - unlike, say, muddiness. Unless there's a feculometer, or something like that.

Comment: Turbid covers all cases of water that is opaque due to suspended particles. Words like muddy are more specific. eg a glacial river is opaque due to suspended rock flour, but you wouldn't call it muddy. Murky refers to the atmosphere (foggy, misty etc)

Comment: +1 for feculent - it certainly gets the image of unclean water across.

Comment: Turbid is the proper word, but doesn't describe color, just transparency and appearance.  In water filtration, turbidity is the level of suspended matter in water, and can be measured: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbidity

Answer (score 22):

*Muddy* is the obvious choice for me.

*Murky* can be [any color](https://www.google.com/search?q=murky+water&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=xZ1&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=IB3hUryMKrTb7Aaal4HYCA&ved=0CDkQsAQ&biw=1040&bih=942), basically anything non-transparent. *Muddy* is [much closer to your description](https://www.google.com/search?q=muddy+water&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Pvg&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Tx3hUqJHpcfsBobdgNgF&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1040&bih=942) of "almost pale brown" and "after a rainy day".

Comment: Muddy can be clean mud, sediment on its way to the sea. I would step in muddy but not in murky water

Comment: @mplungjan Sediment on its way to the sea would be one result of the mineral erosion the question specifically mentions. "Clean mud" is a funny concept to me, but more to the point, making mud *clean* won't make it *transparent*. Just google for ["muddy water"](https://www.google.com/search?q=muddy+water&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=Cqg&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=DBzhUoqjGLL07AaFk4D4DQ&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1040&bih=942) and see for yourself.

Comment: Sure, but prolonged stagnation means smelly to me :)

Comment: true, but stagnant water does not become mud without clay/sand, and in that form it is no longer water

Comment: @RegDwigнt Not to be confused with "[Muddy Waters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muddy_Waters)".

Answer (score 15):

You can call it *opaque*; not able to be seen through; not transparent. You might call it *cloudy* (of a liquid); not transparent or clear. *Nonpotable*, un-fit for drinking.

Other synonyms include *turbid*, *murky*, *unclear*, *muddy*, *thick* and *milky*. You might also use the Shakespearean *hellbroth* (uncommon, but from Macbeth).

Comment: Half of your synonyms are already on this page

Comment: Turbidity is the scientific term used when quantifying the characteristic.  The units that measure turbidity depend on the instrumentation used.  More than you probably want to know:  http://or.water.usgs.gov/grapher/fnu.html

Comment: Hellbroth is my new favorite word.

Comment: +1 for *opaque*, which none of the other answers mention.

Comment: I wouldn't use opaque. If you can see a short distance through it then it's not opaque, it's transparent. You might also call it translucent, but in my mind that applies more to a frosted-glass effect where it's impossible to make out details (no matter how close you get) but light still goes through.

Answer (score 3):

*Stained* is a common fishing term used to describe water that is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This question reminds me of the Indus River dolphin, actually evolved a kind of blindness over years due to the turbidity of the water.  So the words used in these scientific articles are usually **turbid**, **murky**, and they also throw in **silt-laden**.

> The Indus River dolphin is functionally blind having evolved without a crystalline lens or well-developed light-sensitive organ. A deep fold just above the dolphin's mouth is the remnant of what might once have been eyes down the evolution line. However, this is not a disadvantage but an adaptation to living in the ***silt-laden turbid waters*** of the Indus where eyes are virtually useless, as very little light penetrates below the surface of the ***murky*** water.

[src](http://dolphins.jump-gate.com/differnt_dolphins/indus_river_dolphin.shtml)

Comment: "silt-laden turbid ... murky" is a case of too many extra unnecessary adjectives! Not mention superfluous :-)

Comment: How about "the water was so, so turbid, that the dolphins living in it actually evolved a kind of blindness (because they did not need to use their eyes)"

Comment: :-) plus extra stuff to make the comment long enough

Answer (score 2):

Water that is unclean, and no longer transparent is often called murky but there is another adjective, very common and indisputable in its meaning that is used to describe the same phenomenon.  **Filthy water** means water that is *dirty*, *unclean*, *unsafe*, and *impure* to drink from.

There is a TED talk which describes a filter which makes filthy water safe to drink. The title of the talk is: [How to make filthy water drinkable](http://www.ted.com/talks/michael_pritchard_invents_a_water_filter.html#279000)

> Okay, so I'm going to take this really filthy water, and put it in
>   here. Do you want a drink yet?

Comment: I'm going to mix in *skanky* water with your *filthy* water, and perhaps add some *swamp juice* too.

Answer (score 2):

*Mire*.

Not only undesirable [water] but also afflicted with dirt or swamp contaminants.

One could figuratively apply *murling* to water as one would to fire, a play on peatiness.

Comment: So as per the question, we could call the water "Murky and mired with..."

Comment: @nav, no, mire is swamp/marshy ground. "Mired" means to have one's movement impeded by it (usually metaphorically).

Comment: @Ben: I agree. Perhaps "mire" was too strong for this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

you can use misty water for that!!

> > mist•y (ˈmɪs ti)
> >
> > adj. mist•i•er, mist•i•est.
> >
> > 1. covered or obscured by mist.
> > 2. consisting of or resembling mist.
> > 3. indistinct or blurred.
> > 4. obscure; vague.

Reference :  [Misty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misty)

Answer (score 0):

Consider "**[silty](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/silty) [water](http://www.bestofneworleans.com/gambit/a-wasted-opportunity/Content?oid=1778915)**."

> [**silty**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silty): full of silt; of, like, suggestive of silt; soiled